# What is the number of elements of $ |\mathbb{Q} $ \ $ \mathbb{Z}| $?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I know that $| \mathbb{N}|=| \mathbb{Z} | = | \mathbb{Q} |$.

So I assume after this theorem that  $ |\mathbb{Q} $ \ $ \mathbb{Z}|=0 $

Is my assumption correct, and if it's correct, how can I prove it in an appropriate way?

Comment: No, there are rational numbers that are not integers.  Perhaps you can think of one. A more theoretical point: subtraction cannot be defined for infinite cardinals.

Comment: $1/2+n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ gives you an injection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|A\backslash B|=|A|-|B|$ only if $A$ and $B$ are finite set. Here $\mathbb Q\backslash \mathbb Z$ is countable and infinite. Therefore, $$|\mathbb Q\backslash \mathbb Z|=|\mathbb N|.$$

Comment: and does it need no more argumentation? I mean the proof,solution

Comment: You have a theorem that says : If a set $S$ is countable and infinite, then $|S|=|\mathbb N|$. So indeed, you have to prove that $\mathbb Q\backslash \mathbb Z$ is countable and infinite (but it shouldn't be very complicate)

Comment: can you maybe help me to show why is it countable and infinite? unfortunately I still don't know how does it work

Comment: @Zaub: think of $\frac12,\frac13,\ldots$.